# paypal ipn custom variable - sending '$' variable

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I suspect theres an easy answer to this staring me in the face. ive managed to get paypal ipn working well, aside from this little quirk that im struggling to get my head around.

im passing a custom field to paypal, having defined $user_id earlier in the script:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="$user_id">
```

im picking it up in my ipn listener with:

```
$user_id = $_POST['custom'];
```

This process is working fine. The only issue is that instead of the variable being passed, I seem to literally be passing the string $user_id in my custom field. Ive recorded a log of the ipn contents being returned and it shows that $user_id (literally) is being returned from paypal, so this suggests that its $user_id being sent and returned, rather than the actual variable being passed and it being mistranslated on return.

Its probably just an issue with the "" or something, but ive tried all manner of combinations and Im at a loss.

So, direct question - what do i do to the first statement to ensure that an actual variable is sent rather than the literal string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP doesn't just automatically pick up variables in any old page. You need to tell it when to stop/start processing with the `<?PHP ?>` tags.

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?PHP echo $user_id; ?>">
```

Comment: as per my first sentence. feel a bit silly now. thanks, will tick when im allowed.